# how to render cell color after changing cell value Jtable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I have a Jtable with some values [all are Strings] in it. Some values have " * "in front of them which I need to color. I'm able to color those cells which have a  " * " using the Cell Renderer. But after I color the cell, I need to remove the " * " without changing the cell color. When I try to edit the cell value, the color changes back to WHITE. What am I missing in here. 
Here's the code

```
public SimpleTable()
{   
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    setTitle("Colored JTable");
    setBounds(400, 400, 400, 250);
    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    JTable table = new JTable(this.getRows(), this.getHeaders());
    table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);        
    table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new MyTableRenderer());      

    this.scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    panel.add(scrollPane);
    getContentPane().add(panel);
}
```

This is my cell renderer

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column)
{
 Component cellComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

            if(table.getValueAt(row, column).toString().contains("*"))
            {               
                String v = table.getValueAt(row, column).toString().replace("*", "");               
                table.setValueAt(v, row, column);   
                cellComponent.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);              
            }
            else 
            {
                cellComponent.setBackground(Color.WHITE);                   
            }   
        return cellComponent;
```

Answer (score 3):

Options:

1. Leave the * in place in the cell data, use it as a marker for painting, but just don't render it in your renderer.
2. Use a separate non-visualized field of the row, say a boolean, to determine if the cell should be painted red or not.

I favor the latter as a cleaner more OOP solution. Note your cell renderer should be involved with rendering **only**. It should never change the data held by the table, ever.

For an example of the first:

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
    if(value != null && value.toString().contains("*")) {               
        value = value.toString().replace("*", "");               
        setBackground(Color.YELLOW);              
    } else {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);                   
    }   
    return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
```

Comment: The cell value needs to be changed with the color in place. Can you show an example on how to implement the latter solution?

Comment: @SilentCoder: no the value does not need to change. The **display** of the value needs to change -- big difference. For the second answer, that will mean changing the class that constitutes a *row* for the table model's data to include a boolean field.

Comment: The above solution you mentioned is not replacing the * mark.

Comment: @SilentCoder: The code I've posted above will not display the `*` symbol, but for more detailed help, create and post your [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an edit to your question. Don't just say that my solution doesn't work -- show it.

Comment: It is working now !! It was not working previously because of the returned cell component. I see that the cell component initialization was removed. Thanks though. Marked it as answered !!